# How can I convert a hastable to a json string in powershell?

Tags: .net, json, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to convert a hashtable to a json object for use in a web service with powershell 2.0.

```
$testhash = @{
    Name = 'John Doe'
    Age = 10
    Amount = 10.1
    MixedItems = (1,2,3,"a")
    NestedHash = @{
        nestedkey = "nextedvalue"
    }
}

function toJson($obj){

    $ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream
    $type = $obj.getType()
    [Type[]]$types = ($obj | select -expand PsTypeNames |  Select -unique) + [type]'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'
    $js = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer $type, $types, ([int]::MaxValue), $false, $null, $false
    $js.writeObject($ms, $obj) | out-null
    $utf8.GetString( $ms.ToArray(), 0, $ms.Length )
    $ms.Dispose() | out-null
}

toJson $testhash
'[{"Key":"Name","Value":"John Doe"},{"Key":"Age","Value":10},{"Key":"Amount","Value":10.1},{"Key":"NestedHash","Value":[{"__type":"KeyValuePairOfanyTypeanyType:#System.Collections.Generic","key":"nestedkey","value":"nextedvalue"}]},{"Key":"MixedItems","Value":[1,2,3,"a"]}]'
```

I'm using [DataContractJsonSerializer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb919563.aspx) in a way that should suppress type information but it's obviously not. I'm also amused by it's extracting key and value pairs but I'd like to have it not do that either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adapted the script from [here](http://poshcode.org/2930) as below:

```
$testhash = @{
    Name = 'John Doe'
    Age = 10
    Amount = 10.1
    MixedItems = (1,2,3,"a")
    NestedHash = @{
        nestedkey = "nextedvalue"
    }
}

function Read-Stream {
PARAM(
   [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$Stream
)
process {
   $bytes = $Stream.ToArray()
   [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)
}}

function New-Json {
[CmdletBinding()]
param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][HashTable]$InputObject) 
begin { 
   $ser = @{}
   $jsona = @()
}
process {
   $jsoni = 
   foreach($input in $InputObject.GetEnumerator() | Where { $_.Value } ) {
      if($input.Value -is [Hashtable]) {
         '"'+$input.Key+'": ' + (New-JSon $input.Value)
      } else {
         $type = $input.Value.GetType()
         if(!$Ser.ContainsKey($Type)) {
            $Ser.($Type) = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer $type
         }
         $stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
         $Ser.($Type).WriteObject( $stream, $Input.Value )
         '"'+$input.Key+'": ' + (Read-Stream $stream)
      }
   }

   $jsona += "{`n" +($jsoni -join ",`n")+ "`n}"
}
end { 
   if($jsona.Count -gt 1) {
      "[$($jsona -join ",`n")]" 
   } else {
      $jsona
   }
}}

$testHash | New-Json
```

Comment: This seems like something the serialize function should do on it's own, no? Either way - this works almost perfectly - fails on two levels of nested hashes.

Comment: @wizard - It is supposed to be for simple hashtables I think. You can look aroudn, there are already scripts like I have linked to doing JSON parsing.

Comment: I ended up using http://poshcode.org/2930 which has issues but works well enough - one day powershell 3.0 will be available and I will look back on these wasted hours and be upset

Answer (score 16):

Ok, so manojlds answered for v2 so I'll just throw up the v3 equivalent here:

```
PS> @{name="oisin"; age=37} | convertto-json
{
    "age":  37,
    "name":  "oisin"
}
```

Quite a bit cleaner, right?

PowerShell 3.0 CTP2: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27548

Comment: I wish I could use powershell v3 =)

Comment: There's quite a lot of _power_ in this _shell_ :)

Answer (score 0):

A nice clean one-liner.

```
ConvertTo-Json ([System.Management.Automatio.PSObject] $testhash)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.